# CATCH block is triggered when it should not

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, t-sql, error-handling

<sub><sub>On my neverending quest for shooting myself in the foot with save transaction I seem to have found even more ways to fulfill the quest purpose. The save transaction clause itself this time is out of the question, but it is because of it I wrote the code below.</sub></sub>

Consider the following complete example with nested error handlers:

```sql
begin try

  begin try
    select 'Step 1';
  end try
  begin catch
    select 'Step 1 handler - handling ''' + error_message() + '''';
    goto commit_and_exit;
  end catch;

  begin try
    select 'Step 2';
    raiserror('Step 2 error', 16, 1);
  end try
  begin catch
    select 'Step 2 handler - handling ''' + error_message() + '''';
    goto commit_and_exit;
  end catch;

end try
begin catch
  select 'Outer handler - handling ''' + error_message() + '''';
  goto commit_and_exit;
end catch

commit_and_exit:

raiserror('Error raised for the caller to see', 16, 1);
```

[It is documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) that

> `GOTO` statements can be used to jump to a label inside the same `TRY` or `CATCH` block or to leave a `TRY` or `CATCH` block.

Or can it?

Given the code above, a sane programmer would figure the output will be

> Step 1
>   Step 2
>   Step 2 handler - handling 'Step 2 error'
>   <Error raised for the caller to see>

In fact what is happening is:

> Step 1
>   Step 2
>   Step 2 handler - handling 'Step 2 error'
>   Outer handler - handling 'Error raised for the caller to see'
>   <Error raised for the caller to see>

When debugging step by step, I can see that control leaves the try/catch blocks completely, then an error is raised, the control is returned to the outermost `catch` block, that block executes, the control goes to `commit_and_exit:` again, and that final block is executed **again**.

If you have some `commit tran`s or `rollback trans`s under `commit_and_exit:`, you are going to attempt to commit the tran twice. With imaginable results, given the fact there can be outer transactions started by the caller.

I also tried create another label, `end_of_outer:`, right before the outer `end try`, so that the control leaves the outer `try` block "normally". Interesting enough, that did not make any difference.

What the hell is going on, and what is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: I'm not seeing the "Outer handler.." error on SQL Server 2012, but I *am* seeing it on SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Comment: Does this help too? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2074139/27535

Comment: @gbn When specifically applied to transactions, yes, it does (the template is going to be a bit more complex though, as we have sort-of-okay errors that give `XACT_STATE() = 1`, so we rollback to a save point and carry on). But I'm more concerned about the very principle of error handling here, even when to transactions are present. Any code after `commit_and_exit:` is going to execute twice.

Comment: @gbn Are you saying this is a bug in 2008 that has been fixed in 2012? Is there an entry on connect?

Comment: it appears so. I don't know of any Connect article

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/712003/sql-server-2012-error-in-exception-handling-mechanism

Comment: TRY...CATCH has many other problems, so you might be better off if you do more of your error handling on the client.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov Ultimately, errors that client must see are passed to the client. But there are errors that require internal work. Passing them to the client would imply relying on the client to do that work, and that breaks the incapsulation. The database is not an exclusive data storage only used by one application. Many types of clients can connect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like the pre SQL Server 2012 behaviour is a bug.

I infer this from this Connect article:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/712003/sql-server-2012-error-in-exception-handling-mechanism

I could be wrong of course...

Comment: Makes sense to me. The context of a `try` block erroneously survives, so the error functions can return their values, and another consequence would be that an error brings execution into the handler of the erroneously survived `try` context.